# Delete cookie with bad name encode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have problem to remove a cookie with encoded name.

**cookie**

**name:** key%5Fmaquina

**content:** AAAAA

**host:** XXX

**path:** /

On console what I see:

```
(rdb:21) p cookie[:key_maquina]
"AAAAA"
```

And if i do...

```
cookie.delete :key_maquina
```

...doesn't work, the cookie still there... and i have tried...

```
cookie.delete "key%5Fmaquina".to_sym
cookie.delete :"key%5Fmaquina"
```

... doesn't work too.

I want to delete this one, because the new cookie with correct name is not used.. i mean i have two cookies, one with the name *key_maquina* and other with *key%5Fmaquina*

Anyone knows to delete it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please note that if you specify a :domain when setting a cookie, you must also specify the domain when deleting the cookie. `cookies[:key] = {
  :value => 'a yummy cookie',
  :expires => 1.year.from_now,
  :domain => 'domain.com'
}

cookies.delete(:key, :domain => 'domain.com')`

Comment: Yes i have tried with the domain, but I get same result, the cookie stills a live.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
exp_date = 1.day.ago.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y 00:00:00 GMT")
response.headers['Set-Cookie'] = "key%5Fmaquina=; path=/; domain='domain.com'; expires=#{exp_date};"
```

I'm guessing because the expiration date already passed, the browser automatically deletes the cookie.